# Diagram gets disappeared when trying to translate

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm working with OpenGLES 2.0 in android. I need to move an OpenGL object with the taking the x and y axis from the touch event. But when I try to translate the object it acts weird. Same object gets displayed in two places with varying opacity.. and when the finger is lifted both the objects get disappeared.

My translation code is:

```
 Matrix.setIdentityM(mtrxView, 0);
 Matrix.translateM(mtrxView, 0, x, y, 0);
 Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);
```

I'm overriding onTouch() method to handle the ACTION_MOVE event:

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {

        x = ev.getX();
        y = ev.getY();
        deltaX = x - downX;
        deltaY = y - downY;
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        AppLog.v(TAG, "Screen xy cordinate is: " + x + " " + y + " ");
        final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

        switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if(!isZoomInProcess){

                    glRender.requestRender(x, y,GlSurfaceView.this);
                    requestRender();
                }
                break;

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: "Same object gets displayed in two places with varying opacity" and "when the finger is lifted both the objects get disappeared" - The provided code has no effect on any of these problems. I suggest checking out how you handle the touch states.

Comment: @andras I added the code being used to handle touch states